# Square Order - is merchant_token the same as location_id?

Tags: square-connect

I have a Square order.

I want to get the payment record associated with the order (so that I can get `itemization[]`).

I have the `payment_id` from the Square order.  However, I also need the `location_id` from which the order originated to access the endpoint.

The [documentation](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#datatype-order) is not clear where in the `Order` I can get this.

The closest I can find is `merchant_token` (which is not documented, but in the response), but I need to be sure before I build my app around this assumption.

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [List Orders](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#get-orders) endpoint to obtain your `Order` objects? If so, the `location_id` you provide in the path of your request to that endpoint will always be the same as the `location_id` for a returned order's associated payment.

You should rely on this guarantee rather than on the `merchant_token` field returned by the endpoint.

Comment: By the time I am hitting the payment endpoint, the orders have been compiled in a list and disassociated with their original `location_id`s.  But I suppose I can add that to my local `Order` data structure manually.

Comment: However, I would like to lodge a formal "feature suggestion".  An order should be able to stand on its own, containing all of the necessary data for getting related information.  Especially given that order "items" are orphaned on the payment object.